# generic factory method convention

Tags: java, generics

Let me say there is an abstract class which looks like

```java
abstract class Parent<V> {

    protected static <T extends Parent<V>, V> T newInstance(
        final Class<T> type, final V value) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Within following Child class

```java
class Child extends Parent<XXX> {

    public static Child newInstance1(final XXX value) {
        // ...
    }

    public static Parent<XXX> newInstance2(final XXX value) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Which one is preferable? `newInstance1` or `newInstancw2`?

Comment: what does E refer to? is it some concrete existing class or a generic type variable?

Comment: Dear @EyalSchneider I updated the source. sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It actually depends on the scenario in which you are you using the `newInstance()`. In most general cases:

Since `Child` is implementing `newInstance()`, According to me

```
protected static Child newInstance() 
{
    // ...
}
```

would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, factory method defined inside some class returns instance of this particular class, so it should be:

```
public class Foo ...
{
    public static Foo newInstance ()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

regardless of what class this class extends and what interfaces it implements.